# Rails: How to know if checkbox is checked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, checkbox

I'm using rails and I'm trying to know if a check box is checked or not but didn't succeed this is what I'm using actually but didn't worked

```
<% if experience.is_current == 1 %>
```

Update:

this is the experience schema

```
t.date     "experience_start"
t.date     "experience_end"
t.boolean  "is_current"
```

and this is my view

```
<% @profile.experiences.each do |exper| %>
<% if exper.is_current? %>
    <time>to present </time>
<% else %>
    <time> <%= exper.experience_end.strftime('%B-%Y ')  %> </time>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Did you try `<% if experience.is_current? %>`

Comment: no i will try it now

Comment: Can you please see the update

Comment: Your code looks fine. Did you check in the database that you have at least one `experience` that is marked as `is_current`?

Comment: Yes i Have checked this, it was a problem of the dynamic field that i use (add another experience) so when check one all others are checked and i even don't know how to solve this however thank you for the solution

Comment: if you have the solution to your question, don't forget to post it and mark it as answered after the allotted time

Comment: I don't understand what ```checkbox``` means? But with boolean type, your data maybe in 3 values [true, false, nil]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine. Did you check in the database if you have at least one `experience` that is marked as `is_current`?

Comment: you solution <% if experience.is_current? %> is working